Constructing a matrix whose elements are the differences between elements of a vector using the Eigen library in c++
Consider a vector initialized as:
Eigen::Vector<double> A ={a1, a2}

I would like to efficiently construct a matrix like:
 A = 
     {{a11, a12},
     {a21, a22}}

where aij = ai - aj
In other words, the elements of the matrix are differences of the elements of the vector. How can I do this efficiently using the Eigen library in C++?

Pick your poison.
Version 1:
const auto& Ones = Eigen::VectorXd::Ones(A.size());
Eigen::MatrixXd B = A * Ones.transpose() - Ones * A.transpose();

Version 2:
const auto& replicated = A.rowwise().replicate(A.size());
Eigen::MatrixXd B = replicated - replicated.transpose();

Version 3:
Eigen::MatrixXd B(A.size(), A.size());
for(Eigen::Index i = 0, n = A.size(); i < n; ++i)
    B.col(i) = A.array() - A[i];

Version 1 and 3 compile to the best code. If you only use a vector of 2 elements (or other compile-time constant), use the appropriate fixed-size vector and matrix types and replace the dynamic replicate(N) with replicate<N>().
As usual, be careful with using auto and Eigen. The use here is okay.

What you can implement the difference matrix utilizing the Eigen library in C++:
Eigen::VectorXd A(2);
A << 1.0, 3.0;

Eigen::MatrixXd B = A.replicate(1, A.size()) - A.transpose().replicate(A.size(), 1);

